# Use DRF serializer for django's JSONField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to store data which are not always supported by django's default json encoder(?)

For instance I have a `Price` class that has amount and currency.
I have a serializer (DRF) for the instances of this class.

The data that I'd like to save in the json field looks like the following,

```
price_data = {
  'prices': [
    3 : {
      'price': Price(30, currency='usd'),
      'product_variant_id': 3
    },

    5: {
      'price': Price(50, currency='usd'),
      'product_variant_id': 5
    }
  ],
  'seller_prices': [
    8 : {
      'price': Price(30, currency='usd'),
      'product_variant_id': 8
    },

    9: {
      'price': Price(50, currency='usd'),
      'product_variant_id': 9
    }
  ]
}
```

I think I can create a drf-serializer which can serialize/deserialize such data format.

Where should I use this serializer though?

On my model's `__init__() and save()` method? or some other place is preferred?

Comment: that looks like that that shouldn't be in a JSONfield in the first place

Comment: At this point, you need to switch with a fk models instead of a JSONField.

Comment: @e4c5, MaximeK I've made another question to address the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339051/database-modeling-stock-and-product-variant I hope you to look at it.