# Database modeling, stock and product variant

Tags: database, database-design

These are requirements.

1. Multiple sellers are selling product variants.
2. Multiple sellers can sell single product variant at the same time.
   (This requirement can be relaxed if it makes db modeling much simpler.)

The following modeling satisfies the above two requirements.

```
ProductVariant
* id

Stock
* id
* product_variant
* seller
* quantity
* prices
```

There's another requirement

3. Multiple variants might need to share quantity among them.

For instance, a teacher(seller) list his/her product as the following.

A class: $5.00 at 2pm .
B class: $10.00 at 2pm .

The seller is selling A and B classes but he can only receive a certain number of students for the two classes combined. i.e. stock quantity is shared.

To implement the shared quantity, I introduced ProductVariant-Stock relation

```
ProductVariant
* id


ProductvariantStock
* id
* product_variant
* stock

Stock
* id
* seller
* quantity
```

Now the question is, where should I put the price?

The first place I can think of is at the ProductvariantStock

```
ProductvariantStock
* id
* product_variant
* stock
* price # here
```

Another place I can think  of is at the Stock

```
Stock
* id
* seller
* quantity
* price_dict_for_product_variants (as json field)
```

It has the benefit of ability to look up prices with stock table only. And I think I'm accustomed to think 'stock has quantity and price info', and this fits that mental model more closely.

Yet another way is to create a SellerPrice table just for price.

```
SellerPrice
* id
* product_variant
* seller
* price
```

What are the questions I should ask myself to pick a model?

Comment: Why do you name it productvariant and not simply  product?

Comment: you should cleanup  your notation: The table name should be Productvariant an not ProductVariant. And I think it is more clear to name the field in ProductvariantStock that reverences Productvariant productvariant_id.